# Get the public url of an image stored in storage in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, storage

In my `Laravel` project I store users uploaded images in `storage/app/public/images` and I need the public url of each image. I have used the following code:

```
asset(Storage::url('images/'.$image->path);
```

but when I copy the result of it `(http://localhost:8000/storage/images/619cda00e6fcc4.20087443.jpeg)` in browser I get 404. But I can see files out of images folder for example: `http://localhost:8000/storage/619cd898458a94.40743146.jpeg`
I also has ran `php artisan storage:link`.

Comment: Why do you use `post_images` in your code if the files are stored in `images`?

Comment: They are stored in images. I edited my question.

Answer (score -1):

You can set up symbolic links to your file storage in /config/fylesystems.php:

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Symbolic Links
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the symbolic links that will be created when the
    | `storage:link` Artisan command is executed. The array keys should be
    | the locations of the links and the values should be their targets.
    |
    */

    'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
        public_path('images') => storage_path('app/img/'),
        public_path('productos') => storage_path('app/img/productos'),
    ],
```

Then execute 'storage link' Artisan command. With the above example set up, any resource placed in your folder /storage/app/public will can be accessed publicly through http://localhost/storage/some-img.jpg